# Defining variable overrides in SASS / SCSS

Tags: css, sass

I've used sass before and have a question relating to it for functionality I think may or should exist within sass.

Is it at all possible to do something like this, and how:

```
$base-color: #ffffff;
.pink {
  $base-color: #ec008c;
}
.green {
  $base-color: #a4d20e;
}
a, .pink a, .green a {
  color: $base-color;
}
```

Which would mean that I could give a class `.pink` to the `<body>` element, which would make all `<a>` elements within that page "pink". This albeit an oversimplified example seems like something SASS should do.

Which means the above scss would compile so something like so:

```
a {
  color: #ffffff;
}
.pink a {
  color: #ec008c;
}
.green a {
  color: #ec008c;
}
```

Which as I said before is over simplified, consider the following:

```
$base-color: #ffffff;
.pink {
  $base-color: #ec008c;
}
.green {
  $base-color: #a4d20e;
}
.pink, .green {
  #header #nav li a {
    color: $base-color;
  }
}
```

Should give me something like so:

```
.pink #header #nav li a {
    color: #ec008c;
}
.green #header #nav li a {
    color: #a4d20e;
}
```

**This seems like something that should be doable in SCSS/SASS** and would pay A Lot of dividends on larger projects, in both coding time and maintainability.

Comment: Obviously in a proper scenario the compiled CSS would be many lines longer than what would be needed in the SCSS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if there is any way of making SASS work using the syntax that you've proposed, but you can achieve a similar effect using mixins. This is how I would do it:

```
@mixin anchor { color: $base-color; }
@mixin headernav {
  #header #nav { color: $base-color; }
  #header #nav li a { color: $base-color; }
}

$base-color: #ffffff;
a { @include anchor; }
@include headernav;

.pink {
  $base-color: #ec008c;
  a { @include anchor; }
  @include headernav;
}

.green {
  $base-color: #a4d20e;
  a { @include anchor; }
  @include headernav;
}
```

This produces the following CSS output:

```
a {
  color: white; }
#header #nav {
  color: white; }
#header #nav li a {
  color: white; }

.pink a {
  color: #ec008c; }
.pink #header #nav {
  color: #ec008c; }
.pink #header #nav li a {
  color: #ec008c; }

.green a {
  color: #a4d20e; }
.green #header #nav {
  color: #a4d20e; }
.green #header #nav li a {
  color: #a4d20e; }
```

Basically, you could build an entire stylesheet as a mixin, then `@include` that mixin inside of your `.pink` and `.green` classes.

Comment: Seems that the `$base-color` would have to be passed to the `@minin` kinda like so: `.green { @include headernav(#a4d20e); }` etc etc, but otherwise yeah this solution works

Comment: It works fine as I've written it (tested with sass version 3.1.7), but you could also set up the mixin to accept arguments. It might look neater in this case, but if your mixin grew, you might end up with more variables e.g. `$bg-color`, `$highlight-color`, `$active-color`, `$dimmed-color`. In that case, I think it could start to look messy passing them all as arguments when you include the mixin.